# WP8 How to add my app to the lock screen settings

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to programmatically add my app into the allowed lock screen notifications list on Windows Phone 8 / 8.1? Seems like a bit of pain to ask the user to do that themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know you can't set them programmatically. It's a must for the user to add his app to the `lockscreen` from the `Settings`to show the text notification or the icon.

[Lock screen notifications for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj207048(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: After a good search around I've come to the same conclusion. I'm guessing that some of the OS level apps have some sort of special permissions that allow this without user interaction. Thanks. :)